# How to add .htaccess code to apache2.conf?

Tags: 18.04, server, apache2, .htaccess

I want to add my `.htaccess` code into `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

I want to combine these:

> `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

> `/etc/apahce2/apache2.conf` file.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Problem is I don't know where to add `htaccess` code. How can I combine these files?
I am using `Ubuntu 18.04`.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: IMHO the good way to do this is to create a [virtual host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) and use the mod_rewrite configuration inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `.htaccess` file is currently located at `/var/www/.htaccess` then you can literally just *combine* them. `.htaccess` and `<Directory>` containers share the same *directory* "context" - they follow the same (similar) syntax.

In other words:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

However, if you are going to use mod_rewrite directives in a `<Directory>` container then you should consider disabling `.htaccess` altogether (ie. `AllowOverride None`), since `.htaccess` will override the `<Dirctory>` container (by default) and your directives will be ignored.

There is no need for the `<IfModule>` wrapper here since it looks like these directives are mandatory.

A couple of minor points...

- There is no need to backslash escape a literal dot when used inside a regex character class, since it carries no special meaning here. ie. `[^\.]` is the same as `[^.]`.
- The `NC` flag on your `RewriteRule` directive is superfluous since your *pattern* already matches both lower and uppercase letters.
- You explicitly enable directory indexes (`Options Indexes`), yet your mod_rewrite directives effectively prevent directory access anyway. You should probably disable directory indexes.

Bringing these points together, this becomes:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
</Directory>
```

---

An alternative approach, and possibly what @ponsfrilus was suggesting in comments, is to add your mod_rewrite directives directly to the server config (a *server* context) or `<VirtualHost>` container (a *virtualhost* context) - outside of the `<Directory>` container. (Note that if you are already using `<VirtualHost>` containers - preferable - then you will likely *need* to add these directives to the relevant `<VirtualHost>` container. Otherwise, directives in a *server* context will probably just get overridden.)

An advantage of this approach is that they can't then be overridden by `.htaccess`. But if you are disabling `.htaccess` anyway (which you probably should be - since you are moving these directives to your server config) then it doesn't really matter. Also, using mod_rewirte directives outside of a *directory* context is arguably "simpler".

However, the syntax of mod_rewrite directives in a *server* (or *virtualhost*) context is different to a *directory* context, so they need to be changed slightly.

Since directives in a *server* context are processed much earlier, *before* the request is mapped to the filesystem, you can't simply use the `REQUEST_FILENAME` server variable to get the requested filename (which ordinarily holds the absolute filename *after* the request has been mapped to the filesystem). You need to use a lookahead instead. ie. `LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME`.

Also, in a *server* context, the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against is always a root-relative URL-path, starting with a slash. Whereas in `.htaccess` (a *directory* context), the URL-path is less the directory-prefix, so never starts with a slash. In this case, you don't actually need to change anything, but note that what happens is slightly different... in a *server* context you will end up rewriting to a URL-path, whereas in `.htaccess` you are essentially rewriting to a filesystem path (unless you've set a `RewriteBase` directive).

So, alternatively, the above directives could be written as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Updated my answer to include an alternative approach... by adding these directives to the server config (or virtualhost) directly. Although this isn't necessarily "better".

Comment: Thanks for a _really good answer_ and _detailed explanation!_ I used first option and it worked **very well**!